# Spring Cloud Gateway error: 'tokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory' could not be registered

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-security

I'm learning from a Youtube tutorial (https://youtu.be/9b6OOGMpx5Y) to implement a microservices system having about 5 microservices with an API Gateway. The API Gateway is using the Spring Cloud Gateway library which I named "`api-gateway-service`". I'm new to Spring Cloud Gateway and I'm trying to figure out what it's saying here in the error log on application boot up as it seems to be having a problem with Token Relay but I don't know what exactly it is and where is it that it is causing this problem from:

[image: Error Log]

I could set the property `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true` in `application.properties` file so it would be able to boot up the application but Token Relay-ing wouldn't work.

Has anyone approached this error before and do you know a solution to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: In 2020.0.x spring cloud security has been removed. Just remove that dependency as it's now in gateway.

Comment: Thanks, but Token Relay-ing is still not working. It's throwing back HTTP 401 status code.

Comment: I have already set the property `spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters=TokenRelay` but it's not working. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, remove spring-cloud-security dependency from pom or Gradle file

Comment: Hello, @Hieu did you fix this issue?

I have a gateway with keycloak and token relay is not working, it is always asking for login.

Comment: Any update in this? I'm facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory is removed from the spring cloud security and moved to the Spring cloud gateway.

I have recently encoutered this issues. Here, see the documentation [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/spring-cloud-gateway/gatewayfilter-factories/tokenrelay-factory.html)

But first of all make sure you have this dependency in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Instead of Autowiring the TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory, you can do like this

```
@Configuration
@RefreshScope
public class RouteConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public RouteLocator apiRoutes(
      RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder
        .routes()
        .route(
            "CHOICE A ROUTE ID",
            p ->
                p.path("/api/**")
                    .filters(f -> f.tokenRelay())
                    .uri("http://localhost:8080"))
        .build();
  }
}
```